# when users upload an image how can i use css to minimize skewing?

Tags: css, image, styles

I allow users to upload a profile pic to their profile page. The dimensions of the avatar are 100px x 100px. How can i edit my img properties style in css so that when users upload images that are not perfectly square, the image distortion is minimized?

Comment: How will you know if the image needs adjustment or not?

Comment: @mblase75: If the image is not square.

Comment: @Truth All image files are rectangular. Do you mean you want them to be perfectly square?

Comment: He said so himself. If the images are not perfectly square, minimize the distortion. He also stated that all images should be 100px x 100px.

Comment: @Truth He also used the word "skewing" in the headline, which means something entirely different. I wanted to be sure of his intentions.

Comment: I won't edit the title because (even though it's probably wrong), but let's wait for the OP to explain his choice of wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial to crop an image in CSS -- wrap it in a DIV and hide the overflow:

```
div.imgwrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem, though, is that if the image is very large -- say 600px by 400px -- then you'll just be seeing a tiny corner of the entire thing. And if the image is smaller than 100px by 100px, it won't be resized upwards.

The only (client-side) way to solve this is by using JavaScript to detect the image's dimensions, and even then it gets tricky (because you can't detect image dimensions until after the image is loaded, but you can't detect image load vs. image from cache without some further trickery). I won't go into details because you didn't ask for a JS solution, but you can [search SO for a few solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+resize+onload+javascript&submit=search).

Answer (score 2):

**[Crop it](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1709-cropping-images-using-php.html)** instead of changing it's dimensions normally. Even with resampling it would distort the image. Have the user crop the image he uploaded (using canvas/javascript) and have the PHP script crop the image according to the coordinates gained from that.

Answer (score 0):

You could either crop the image on upload like @Truth mentioned or use a script like [TimThumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) that crops the original sized image on the fly to whatever dimensions you need it to be.

Comment: OP specifically asked for CSS solutions, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to some method of cropping the image through code, an alternative it to use a 100px/100px `div`, and set the uploaded image as the background of this div, with it's horizontal/vertical position set centrally.

Of course, you will want to check the filesize of the uploaded image, otherwise you may end up with 20 3Mb profile images being loaded on one page.